# What are the limitations of svn hotcopy?

Tags: svn, restore

We are about to upgrade our infrastructure and change the operating system in use (upgrade to RHEL5).

We will also move our SVN repository from our current servers to the new RHEL5 servers, however - I'm not sure how we should do this change. 
I remember reading once that if I use the hotcopy command, the copy created can only be restored on a machine with the same OS as the OS taking the backup. 
Is this correct? Will I be able to restore the copy of the repository on the RHEL5 server even if I took the backup on a RHEL4 server?

Also, if we were to also upgrade our SVN server version, would I be able to restore  the copy on a different version of the SVN server taking the backup?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*When* and *if* you want to change infrastructure of Subversion host, hotcopy will be wrong choice. You **must** to use svnadmin dump|load procedure.

Most times backups of old SVN-repos can be easy restored on new versions, but better to read changelog between for all versions between used and planned. Can't recall anything before 1.5, but, AFAIR, 1.5-1.7 upgrade for FSFS was transparent.

Anyway, you can install old version, load data into repo and update server after it

Add: svn load can handle dumps, created by previous versions, without any problem

Comment: Dump/Reload is *very* slow for large repos. If you are using FSFS it is safe to file copy all content to new server. FSFS repos are platform and upwards compatible

Comment: @Peter-parker I know, but dump is editable by hand, after all

Comment: Why do you want to edit the dump by hand?! This is the best way to obstruct your dumpfile!

Comment: I **don't want** and do not do it, but for *some requests* it's a single way to get results (imagine "rebase" in SVN, change author's name) and **it's possible** to edit dump without disasters

Comment: I do not know what you mean by rebase, but to change authors name, just use svnadmin setrevprop

Comment: @PeterParker -  Rebase - changing order of commits (set of commits), regarding setrevprop: don't make me fool!!! Try to do svnadmin for 1000-5000-10000 revisions and share impressions after it

Answer (score 0):

You do not need svnadmin hotcopy.

Your memory about backups is not correct:
FSFS-Repositories are platform neutral. You can use the same repository on a unix machine or on a windows machine. You can also upgrade the server binaries without worrying about repository version.

You just can filecopy all repositories as long as you have **FSFS** repo types.
Hotcopy is badly slow on large repos.

For consistency you should disable write access on source repo.
 Easiest way is to create a pre-commit hookscript with this single line:

```
exit 1;
```

Just to make sure:
This is **not true for BDB-Repositories** as since svn 1.3 FSFS repo type is default I presume you have a FSFS repository.

However, It is crucial to check the integrity of your copied repository with:

```
svnadmin verify <PATH_TO_REPO>
```

After this all your doubts about the integrity should be gone ;-)

Answer (score 0):

99% of the time, you can probably get away with using a hot copy instead of a dump. However, you and I both know that the rare 1% of the time when a hot copy won't work will be the time your career will depend upon it.

So, do an `svnadmin dump` as part of your backup procedure. You can do an `svnadmin dump` of the most recent changes if doing an `svnadmin dump` of your whole repository would take too long.

I do both a hot copy and dump as a backup.